# Agrupar datos en dataframe por filas

Tags: r, dataframe, agrupación

Tengo un dataframe con varios valores en una fila que se relacionan y me gustaría agruparlos. Cada número código "GO_" corresponde con una descripción. Pongo ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame("Protein"= c("a", "b"),"ID"= c("F_GO_0015;F_glycine","F_GO_00037;F_GO_00041;F_mRNA;F_cysteine"))
df
```

```
 Protein     ID
1       a F_GO_0015;F_glycine
2       b F_GO_00037;F_GO_00041;F_mRNA;F_cysteine
```

```
df.new <-data.frame("Protein"= c("a", "b"),"ID"= c("F_GO_0015-F_glycine","F_GO_00037-F_mRNA;F_GO_00041-F_cysteine"))
df.new
```

```
        Protein ID
    1       a    F_GO_0015-F_glycine
    2       b    F_GO_00037-F_mRNA;   F_GO_00041-F_cysteine
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes dividir por el carácter `;`, separar en dos mitades y luego pegar colapsando el resultado con el mismo carácter:

```
dividir_y_unir <- function(x){
  x <- unlist(strsplit(x,split = ';'))
  x1 <- x[1:(length(x)/2)]
  x2 <- x[(1+length(x)/2):length(x)]
  return(paste(x1,x2,sep='-', collapse = ';'))
}

df$ID <- sapply(df$ID,dividir_y_unir)
df
#  Protein                                      ID
#1       a                     F_GO_0015-F_glycine
#2       b F_GO_00037-F_mRNA;F_GO_00041-F_cysteine
```